# ArcGIS WebApp Near Me widget is missing features

Tags: arcgis-server, widget

When I set up the Near Me widget in my Web App configured to 'Only draw selected layer results' the map view does not display all of the features in my layers (even before I have selected a layer in the results list). I would like to use this option but I cannot trust the results.

Have a missed something?

Everything displays fine when this option is not selected or when not using Near Me.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify and tag what software you are asking about.

Comment: More detail is always better than less. Are you using AGOL, or Enterprise? Is this the out-of-the-box Web App Builder, or the dev version? Specifically in the widget, what are the other settings, and how many layers are interacting with the widget? I just tested a few setups with the widget, and all perform as expected.